# Count on sObject

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql

EDIT:

What I'm asking is, do I have to execute two separate query one for retrieving the information and one for count? is that possible to put both together in one query?

in the .NET you just have to count on the List to get the count and I'm not sure how does in SF/SOQL works.

Is there any other way to count number of records return

One way to do is to follow this:

```
String soql = 'select count() from lead where Ownerid=:18digit_id and IsConverted=false';
Integer leadCount = Database.countQuery(soql);
```

Comment: I'm not 100% on what you're asking, but I'm guessing no. How would you get database information without querying the database?

Comment: I have updated my question please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to know how many records the SOQL query returned and have a collection with all the results?

Much like .NET, you can use the [List.size()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_list.htm) method on the list to get the count.

```
List<lead> leadsForOwner = [select id from lead where Ownerid=:18digit_id and IsConverted=false];
Integer leadCount = leadsForOwner.size();
for(Lead leadForOwner : leadsForOwner) { 
    //...
}
```

As Adrian commented, you should give some thought for how this will scale when the number of leads increases.

Something like the following will reduce the number of leads that need to be held in memory at any one time.

```
Integer leadCount = 0;
for(Lead leadForOwner : [select id from lead where Ownerid=:18digit_id and IsConverted=false]) { 
    //...
    leadCount++;
}
```

Comment: You don't really need to load all the rows on the heap to get that number. If you had a lead skew where someone owned, say, 12K leads this would be a major difference.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Definitely, consideration should be make for how many leads that SOQL query might return. I was addressing the simplest case for the question where one query could be used to get the both the total record count and a collection that could then be iterated.

Comment: Why will you need 2 separate queries, If you want to get only the count you can use query like this                                                                 SELECT count(Id) Project_Status__c, Project_Phase__c FROM Project__c group by Project_Phase__c                                                                             and if you are getting the records from DB, you will be getting in a List and can check list size. Not sure what is the problem statement here.

Comment: Yeah I also didn't read it thoroughly enough... sorry.